# Remove duplicates from hive table using group by

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table like this.a,b,c,d,e are the columns of table

[image]

I want to find distinct records on a combination of group by(d,e) and do some operation on the table
The final table should remove duplicate keys.

The final table should look like below

[image]

I have done a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT a+"cis" as a_1,
             b+"cis1" as b_1,
             c as c_1,
             d+"cis2" as d_1,
             e as e_1
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d, e order by d,e) as cnt
      FROM table1
      
     ) x
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

I am getting results like

[image]

How can I get the actual result

Thanks in advance

Comment: You tell us, was the result of that query what you expected?

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried it? Was that right or wrong? If wrong, why? Also, please don't post abridged code (`--give my where condition--`).

Comment: @Magnus,@underscore_d sorry that was a miss from my end.II have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I think i found a solution

```
SELECT concat(x.a,"cis") as a_1,concat(x.b,'cis1') as b_1,x.c as c_1,
             concat(x.d,'cis2') as d_1,x.e as e_1 FROM (SELECT a,b,c,d,e,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d, e order by d,e) as cnt FROM table  ) x
WHERE cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way -

```
SELECT concat(a,'cis') as a_1,
             concat(b,'cis1') as b_1,
             c as c_1,
             concat(d,'cis2') as d_1,
             max(e) as e_1
       FROM table1
group by concat(a,'cis'),concat(b,'cis1'),c,concat(d,'cis2')
```

Comment: I am actually trying to avoid group by.There are a lot of columns.So If i do a group by I have to include all the columns.

Comment: do you've any date column @Nils

Comment: Yes @Fahmi.I have date columns

Comment: @Nils, could you please add the date column to your sample data?

Comment: @Fahmi.I think I found a way.The query is working now.You still want the date column?I can edit in the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your are using `row_number()`.  How about this?

```
SELECT concat(x.a, 'cis') as a_1, concat(x.b, 'cis1') as b_1, x.c as c_1,
       concat(MIN(x.d), 'cis2') as d_1, x.e as e_1F
FROM t
GROUP BY x.a, x.b, x.c, x.e
```

You should also be able to use `||` for string concatenation:

```
SELECT (x.a || 'cis') as a_1, (x.b || 'cis1') as b_1, x.c as c_1,
       (MIN(x.d) || 'cis2') as d_1, x.e as e_1F
FROM t;
```

Comment: row_number() to remove duplicate records.If you see my question there is one row which I have highlighted in red.I want to remove that column

Comment: @Nils . . . I see.  I replaced it with `GROUP BY`.